React native expo sqlite/next data is not showing in db file while file is open in DB Browser
I'm new to React Native Expo and I'm trying to use SQLite for storing data locally in my app. I followed a tutorial and managed to set up the database using the expo-sqlite package. Everything seems to be working fine, but when I try to check the data in the SQLite database file using DB Browser for SQLite, I can't see any of the data I've inserted.
Here's a simplified version of my code:
async function insertData(data_to_submit) {
    try {
      const result = db.runAsync(
        `INSERT INTO BizUser (
          WhiteLabelURL, BizUser, BizUserPassword, BizUserName, BizUserEmail, 
          BizUserCell, BizUserAddress, BizUserClass, BizLocationLatitude, 
          BizLocationLongitude, BizLocationDescription, BizFeaturedImage, 
          ActiveStatus, ActiveStatusDateTime, SignupDateTime, BizLastUpdate, 
          BizLastUpdateDateTime
        ) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);`,
        [
          data_to_submit.WhiteLabelURL,
          data_to_submit.BizUser,
          data_to_submit.BizUserPassword,
          data_to_submit.BizUserName,
          data_to_submit.BizUserEmail,
          data_to_submit.BizUserCell,
          data_to_submit.BizUserAddress,
          data_to_submit.BizUserClass,
          data_to_submit.BizLocationLatitude,
          data_to_submit.BizLocationLongitude,
          data_to_submit.BizLocationDescription,
          data_to_submit.BizFeaturedImage,
          data_to_submit.ActiveStatus,
          data_to_submit.ActiveStatusDateTime,
          data_to_submit.SignupDateTime,
          data_to_submit.BizLastUpdate,
          data_to_submit.BizLastUpdateDateTime,
        ]
      );

      const allUsers = await db.getAllAsync("SELECT * FROM BizUser");

      console.log("Data inserted successfully", result);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error inserting data:", error);
    }
  }

Even though the console logs show that the data is being inserted and retrieved successfully, I can't see anything when I open the mydb.db file in DB Browser for SQLite.
Can someone please help me understand why the data isn't showing up in the database file? Am I missing a step or misunderstanding something about how SQLite works with React Native Expo?
Any advice or explanations would be really helpful. Thanks a lot!

I just had this same issue and realized that expo-sqlite is creating a new local database based on the database file you provide. It doesn't actually update or write to the original source file it just uses it as a seed to create a new database.
Hope that helps.

any way to get the auctual db

It creates a local database based on your db file (that is like a seed for devices).
How to open that local database or update it? - not sure how to update only part of that database, but to delete it you need to go to phone settings -> apps -> your app -> storage -> clear storage and clear cache. The database will reset to your db file (with updated data).
